# XML and Google Maps, only one marker showing (of four)

Tags: google-maps

I've a problem with my code.  I can get the lat and lng to load from the xml file and display it on google maps, but it only displays the first record (there are 4 in total).

I'm 100% confident the xml is fine, I just can't figure out how to display all the markers on googles map.

Any help would be great!

```
  function initialize() {
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.956086, -9.140625);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 13,
  center: myLatlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
jQuery.get("markers.xml", {}, function(data) {
  jQuery(data).find("marker").each(function() {
    var marker = jQuery(this);
    var Lat = $(this).find('lat').text();
    var Lng = $(this).find('lng').text();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(sLat), parseFloat(Lng));
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latlng, map: map});
 });
});
```

}

Comment: Is this your exact code?  There are several errors - `sLat` isn't defined, and you declare `var marker` twice.

Comment: Your method works for a simple xml and fixed syntax error: http://jsfiddle.net/Jeff_Meadows/v2BJC/  Can you show us your XML?

Answer (score -1):

Any logs/errors with tools like firebug?
looks good from what I can tell (2 problems: you initialize marker 2 times and sLat is not defined).

Are you sure it's looping each 4 times and not only once?
Had you debugged that?

Comment: I tried resting the browser settings, cache ect and that seemed to have fixed it.